# Find the same string in mysql table between certain column values

Tags: mysql

I have a table in MySQL database let's call it `products`:

```
id_product | id_lang | name
-----------+---------+-----
       654 |       1 | abc
       654 |       2 | xyz
       654 |       3 | abc
       456 |       1 | qwe
       456 |       2 | rty
       456 |       3 | zxc
       123 |       1 | bnm
       123 |       2 | bnm
       123 |       3 | jkl
       789 |       1 | ert
       789 |       2 | tyu
       789 |       3 | ert
       333 |       1 | ddd
       333 |       2 | o
       333 |       3 | bbb
       222 |       1 | xxx
       222 |       2 | zzz
       222 |       3 | o
```

I would like to find all `id_product` which have the same `name` in `id_lang` **1** and **3**. So result in this case should be id_product: 654 and 789. It would be great if in this query could find also all `id_product` where `id_lang` is 3 and `name` is "o". So result should be `id_product`: 654, 789 and 222. But if it is too complicated I can have two queries and merge two array's in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following solution using `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`. With `UNION` you can merge two querys to get one result:

```
SELECT id_product 
FROM products
WHERE id_lang IN (1, 3) 
GROUP BY id_product, name 
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
UNION
SELECT id_product
FROM products
WHERE id_lang = 3 AND name = 'o'
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b9d3fcb3d277db8be010655ff1d46c37)

---

To get your first expected result you can use the following query:

```
-- result of this query: 654 and 789
SELECT id_product 
FROM table_name 
WHERE id_lang IN (1, 3) 
GROUP BY id_product, name 
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1
```

To get your second result you can use the following query:

```
-- result of this query: 222
SELECT id_product
FROM table_name
WHERE id_lang = 3 AND name = 'o'
```

To join these two results you can merge the querys by using [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html) (see solution at the beginning).

Answer (score 2):

Including the first part of the query from @Sebastian
and adding the second piece with a Union

```
SELECT 
    id_product
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    id_lang IN (1 , 3)
GROUP BY id_product , name
HAVING COUNT(name) > 1    
UNION
SELECT 
    id_product
FROM
    table_name
WHERE
    id_lang = 3 AND name = 'o'
```